# Single page app stopped working after routing

Tags: angularjs, uiviewcontroller, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, angularjs-material

I'm new to AngularJS and trying to make a simple single page app. Everything worked perfectly, but then I added states with $stateProvider and when I click on the buttons which have assigned functions, nothing happens like there is a problem in controllers. 
I'll appreciate if you can help me. The code may be quiet long but I can't move further on my own.
Here is the code:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/customMaterial.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="ngClassifieds">

   <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="classifiedsCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="components/classifieds/classifieds.fac.js"></script>
    <script src="components/classifieds/new/newClassified.ctr.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***classifieds.tpl.html***

```
<md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <p>Pixo</p>
        <md-button ng-click="vm.openSidenav()">
            <md-icon class="mdi mdi-plus-circle"></md-icon>
            Add new
        </md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="filtering = !filtering">
            <md-icon class="mdi mdi-magnify"></md-icon>
            Filter
        </md-button>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>

<ui-view></ui-view>

<div class="filters" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-show="filtering">
    <md-input-container style="margin-top:43px">
        <label>Enter search term</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="filter" />
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <label>Category</label>
        <md-select ng-model="category" placeholder="Select a category">
            <md-option ng-repeat="category in vm.categories" value="{{category}}" ng-bind="category"></md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="category='';filter=''">
            Clear <md-icon class="mdi mdi-backspace"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </md-input-container>

</div>



<md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <md-card flex="30" ng-repeat="classified in vm.classifieds | filter:filter
                 |filter: category" class="classified">
        <img ng-src="{{classified.img}}" alt="phone" style="height:300px !important" />

        <md-card-content>
            <div class="classified-info" ng-show="!showContact">
                <h2 class="md-title" ng-bind="classified.title"></h2>
                <h3 ng-bind="classified.price | currency:'€'"></h3>
                <p ng-bind="classified.description">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="classified-contact" ng-show="showContact">
                <p><md-icon class="mdi mdi-account"></md-icon><span ng-bind="classified.contact.name"></span></p>
                <p><md-icon class="mdi mdi-phone"></md-icon><span ng-bind="classified.contact.phone"></span></p>
                <p><md-icon class="mdi mdi-email"></md-icon><span ng-bind="classified.contact.email"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div layout="row">
                <md-button ng-click="showContact = true" ng-show="!showContact">Contact</md-button>
                <md-button ng-click="showContact = false" ng-show="showContact">Details</md-button>
                <md-button ng-click="showAdmin = true" ng-show="!showAdmin">Admin</md-button>
                <md-button ng-click="showAdmin = false" ng-show="showAdmin">Cancel</md-button>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ng-show="showAdmin">
                <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="vm.editClassified(classified)">EDIT</md-button>
                <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="vm.deleteClassified($event,classified)">DELETE</md-button>
            </div>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
```

***newClassified.tpl.html***

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id='left' class="md-sidenav-left">
    <md-toolbar>
        <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">Add new</h2>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        <form>
            <md-input-container>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" autofocus ng-model="classified.title" />
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="classified.price" />
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea ng-model="classified.description"></textarea>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label for="image">Image link</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="classified.image" />
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="vm.saveClassified(classified)" ng-if="!vm.editing">SAVE</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-primary" ng-if="vm.editing" ng-click="vm.saveEdit()">SAVE EDIT</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="vm.closeSidenav()">CANCEL</md-button>
        </form>
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

***app.js***

```
angular.module("ngClassifieds", ["ui.router", "ngMaterial"])
.config(function ($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('teal')
    .accentPalette('orange');

    $stateProvider.state("classifieds", {
        url: '/classifieds',
        templateUrl: 'components/classifieds/classifieds.tpl.html',
        controller: 'classifieds as vm'
    })
    .state('classifieds.new', {
        url: '/new',
        templateUrl: 'components/classifieds/new/newClassified.tpl.html',
        controller: 'newClassified as vm'
    });
});
```

***classifiedsCtrl.js***

```
(function () {

angular
    .module("ngClassifieds")
    .controller("classifieds", function ($scope, $http, classifiedsFactory, $mdSidenav, $mdToast, $mdDialog) {

        var vm = this;
        var classifieds;
        vm.openSidenav = openSidenav;
        vm.closeSidenav = closeSidenav;
        vm.saveClassified = saveClassified;
        vm.editClassified = editClassified;
        vm.saveEdit = saveEdit;
        vm.deleteClassified = deleteClassified;

        vm.classifieds;
        vm.categories;
        vm.editing;
        vm.classified;

        classifiedsFactory.classifiedsData().then(function (classifieds) {

            vm.classifieds = classifieds.data;
            vm.categories = getCategories(vm.classifieds);

        });

        function getCategories(classifieds) {
            var categories = [];
            angular.forEach(classifieds, function (classified) {
                angular.forEach(classified.categories, function (category) {
                    categories.push(category);
                });
            });
            return _.uniq(categories);
        }


        function openSidenav() {
            $mdSidenav('left').open();
        }
        function closeSidenav() {
            $mdSidenav("left").close();
        }

        var showSavedToast = function (message) {
            $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple()
                .content(message).position("right", "top").hideDelay(3000));
        }
        var contact = {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "phone": "545 555 655",
            "email": "john.doe@mail.com"
        }
        function saveClassified(classified) {

                classified.contact = contact;
                vm.classifieds.push(classified);
                classified = {};
                closeSidenav();
                showSavedToast("Classified saved");

        }
        function editClassified(classified) {
            vm.editing = true;
            vm.classified = classified;
            openSidenav();
        }
        function saveEdit() {
            vm.editing = false;
            vm.classified = {};
            vm.closeSidenav();
            showSavedToast("Classified edited");
        }
        function deleteClassified(event, classified) {
            var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
                            .title("Are you sure you want to delete " + classified.title + "?")
                            .textContent("This item will be deleted permanently")
            .ok('Yes')
            .cancel('No');
            $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
                var index = vm.classifieds.indexOf(classified);
                vm.classifieds.splice(index, 1);
            }, function () { });
        }
    });})();
```

***newClassified.ctr.js***

```
(function () {
angular.module('ngClassifieds')
    .controller('newClassified', function ($mdSidenav, $mdDialog, classifiedsFactory, $timeout) {

        var vm = this;
        $timeout(function () {

            $mdSidenav('left').open();
        });
    });})();
```

Comment: It's nice that you added the problematic code, but we can't help if we don't get any details about the errors you are getting. What does it say in the console of the browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the default state in app.js

```js
        .state('classifieds',{
            url:'/classifieds',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/mergeTemplate5.html'            
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/classifieds');
```

and if you are redirecting from one state to another you need to add the following code in controller

```html
 <a  name="AdvSearch" id="btnAdvSearch" ng-click="GoToNew()" ></a>
```

```html
 $scope.GotoNew = function() {
            $state.go('classified.new');
        };
```